# Qt creator has cmakelists load into project

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, qt-creator

[The screen-spot of the demo project I build in Qt creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9CJl.png)
I have a Source directory with several .cpp, .h and CMakeLists.txt files. I want to import this director as a project in Qt creator. There is now .pro file in my source directory. I tried the following two methods, however I still can't load this director into Qt creator.

1. first method in Qt creator: File-> Import Project -> Import Existing Project, then it ask me to give the "project name and location". Once I gave the location of my existing source directory, Qt just built a new project for me, however, I can't see my CMakeLists.txt file in the new project. How to load my existing source files into Qt as a project with my own CMakeLists.txt??
2. second method in Qt creator: File->Non-Qt Project->Plain C++ Application, then click choose. By this method, it can build a new project with main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt in the directory, as shown in the figure. However, once I right click the mouse on the name of the project "untitled", it seems "Add New", "Add Existing Files", "Add Existing Directories", "New subproject", and "Add library"  can't be used, therefore I can add new .cpp files into this project??? Is there someone can help me figure this out?? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Qt Creator 3.6.1 and the latest version handles CMake based projects much better than the previous versions. Perhaps you should give it a try?
Here's the link to the latest beta;
http://download.qt.io/snapshots/qtcreator/. Of course it's not a released product yet, but I have found it to be very stable. Your mileage may vary though.

Regarding question 2, as you said "Add New", "Add Existing Files", "Add Existing Directories", "New subproject", and "Add library" are disabled because you would have to manage the project through cmake. You can edit CmakeLists.txt and rerun cmake again through "build" -> "Run CMake" or click to "Project" and "Run CMake" button on the Reconfigure project column.

If you need to create new files in the folder, then you can right click on the sub-folder name and click on "Open Terminal Here" and add/copy the needed files or choose "Show Containing Folder" for file manager.

EDIT:
to add another library to your project .pro file, here's an example;

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/boost
LIBPATH     += /usr/local/lib/boost
LIBS        += -lboost_system
```

notice it's `-l`, not `-L`.

based on the above, your .pro should be like this;

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
LIBPATH += /usr/local/lib/
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

(depends on which opencv libs you will need, like -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml or others). If you need more, then you will have to supply the name of those libs.

============================================================

UPDATED:
From your code, here is what I tested (successfully compiled and executed);
code:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("diffuse.png"); 
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    cv::imshow("My image",image);
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
#RESOURCES += qml.qrc
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
LIBPATH += /usr/local/lib/
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

Notice that I commented out `qml.qrc` because I don't have it. So my suggestion is for you to comment out `qml.qrc`, compile and run the code. If everything is OK, that means the source of error is probably somewhere in `qml.qrc` with regard to the image file.

============================================================

EDIT:
Make sure that the image is in the folder as the **executable file**, not with the **source code file**

HTH

Comment: Thanks, the answer for question works. For question, I installed Qt creator 5.5.1 which I think is the latest version, what's the difference between the Qt creator you mentioned? If I build a new project with .pro file, can I change the .pro file to CMakeLists.txt file? What is the difference between CMakeLists.txt and .pro in Qt?? I found the contents in both files look the same.

Comment: Your Qt Creator comes in bundled with Qt 5.5.1 which means you are using the latest stable release of Qt Creator, that is one version older then the one I mentioned above. You can click on "Help" and go to "About Qt creator" to know the exact version of your installation. As for the second question, there is no auto converter to change .pro to CMakeLists.txt for your project. You will have to do the conversion manually. That being said, however, it's not hard to do the conversion once you have a basic template ready, as you can use the same template for various projects with minor changes. HTH

Comment: Check my updated answer. Let me know if it's working.

Comment: I use opencv3.0.0 in Qt. The .pro file has the following contents: TEMPLATE = app, QT += qml quick widgets, CONFIG += c++11, SOURCES += main.cpp, RESOURCES += qml.qrc, INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/, LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/,#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>, the contents in main.cpp is #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>, #include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>,int main(), {cv::Mat image = cv::imread("My.JPG"); cv::namedWindow("My Image");cv::imshow("My image",image);cv::waitKey(5000);return 1;}. The error is undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int), can u help me?Thanks.

Comment: So how's everything? You should be able to compile the code using the provided .pro file provided you created the right .qrc file. However, from your code you didn't actually use .qrc file so if you commented out the `RESOURCES += qml.qrc` file you should be able to compile your code without any problem. If indeed your problem has been solved, would you mind to `accept` the answer as to close this thread? Thanks.

Comment: See my newly updated answer. I just tested your code and I could compile and run the code with no problem.

Comment: Hi, I use the code you provided but it still has 3 errors. I am still confused about those errors.                         :-1: error: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi' /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0                                                          :-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line          :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: add `-lopencv_imgcodecs` to the `LIBS +=` section in your .pro

Comment: Add -lopencv_imgcodecs, it still has two errors: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 279
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:279: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Comment: Are you sure the image is in the same folder? You should know that the image must be in the _build folder_, not the _source code folder_. Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) indicates that either the program could not locate the image or the image is not valid, otherwise the image's width and height should be greater than 0.

Comment: I moved the image from source code folder to build folder, then it works. I also tried to put the image inside the source code folder, but in the main function I use the whole path: /users/ruby/untitiled/my.jpg, it also works. Does it mean I can only use the whole path? thanks.

Comment: Glad that it works. You can also use a relative path, like so; `std::string path = "../images/image.png";` and supply that to OpenCV. Just remember that it's the **executable** that uses the image (or other resources), not the **source**, so you must supply all the needed resources to the executable(s).

Comment: Would you tag the reply as the accepted answer? This could help other users who are having the same problem as your question is tagged as answered in the database. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how to tag the reply as the accepted answer, can you tell me?

Comment: Here's a link on how to tag an answer and what an answer really is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Quoting the link; `Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question.`. You may read the link to know how this could help you with your future questions and how you can help other users too as we all learn more stuffs about programming here. Cheers.